# #N/A in all fields

Tags: dashboard-designer-2013, sql-analysis-services

I'm trying to display my data in a dashboard from a cube. However the data displays as #N/A in all fields.

[image: Dashboard Designer]

However in VS I'm able to actually see the data.

[image: Visual Studio]

I'm sure this is probably a settings issue I need to find. But I'm not finding it. Any help will be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by deleting the cube and re creating it.